# Need to disable hardware acceleration in Arch Linux?

Tags: arch-linux, xorg, mesa, amdgpu

Found out that Hardware Acceleration when using a AMD Ryzen 9 5900HX will cause video lockups or system reboots. Using a Minisforum HX90 computer. Using open-source drivers and admgpu. No error msg, justs locks up or reboots. All drivers, OS and software updated and current. Been using Linux for a while, but have not run into this type of problem before and have not studied Arch Linux internals. How do I disable this feature from AMDgpu.  Thanks.

Comment: HW acceleration of what?

Comment: and if you don't know how to turn it off, how do you know it's to blame?

Comment: I have read multiple comments about the amd graphics having problems with both linux and windows with video locks and reboots. All cards have a similar cpu/gpu as my computer.  The solution is to adjust the gpu in windows with the amd software, however, linux does not have benefit of this software.